# Comparative adverb vs. comparative adjective

Tags: grammaticality, comparatives

I am a little torn on which usage is correct here, the comparative adjective "easier" or the comparative adverb "more easily."

1. Every other day this year will begin easier than this one ...
2. Every other day this year will begin more easily than this one ...

Or are they interchangeable in this instance?

Thanks.

Comment: In this case you need a _comparative adverb_ as you are modifying the verb "begin" not the noun "day". "Easier" is an adjective and "more easily" is an adverbial phrase so you need "more easily".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [easier, more easily, or easy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232615/easier-more-easily-or-easy)

Comment: @BoldBen 'Easier' is not always an adjective. 'It's easier said than done.'

Comment: You can look at it a couple of different ways: **1**. *Easy* is an adjective: *The day will begin [being] easy.* (cf. *The day will begin [being] sunny.*). And *easily* is an adverb: Today will begin how? *Today will begin easily.* **2**. *Easy* is the flat adverb version of the adverb *easily*. Today will begin how? *Today will begin easy.* Since the day probably won't have any trouble getting itself started, you probably want the adjective interpretation. (Use *easy* / *easier*.)

Comment: You got a laugh out of me, Tinfoil, with "the day won't have any trouble..." Well done. It wasn't to personify the noun. Here it is with more context:

Comment: "Quieted by their nerves, they eye a brick, hub-and-spoke building situated at the top of the incline. Every other day this year will begin easier than this one, their first of fourth grade, but they can't see their way clear to that yet."